# query for siblings in solr- nested document

Tags: solr, nested-documents

I am new to `Solr` and specifically nested documents. I am stuck in querying by child and then return it along with all siblings (children of same parent
I was able to retrieve the parent child but stuck in how to return all the children.

The child query:

```
{!parent which="*:* -_nest_path_:*"}(country:"Germany") where country=Germany
```

Any help?